# xamarin object not set to an instance - camera image

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using an class to get bitmap from camera called (Apps.bitmap), now I want to convert this bitmap to base46 for upload to server but I getting error object not set to an instance

My code

```
       var bitmaps = Apps.bitmap;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmaps.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);
        byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();
             string myimage = Convert.ToBase64String(ba);
```

the error point to this line

```
            bitmaps.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);
```

Comment: Did you check if that Apps.Bitmap that you get your value from is returning you any thing or is it returning null?

Comment: What is `Apps`?